# How much is Classical Hebrew (in which the Hebrew Bible is written) is different from the modern Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew

How much is Classical Hebrew (in which the Hebrew Bible is written) is different from the modern Hebrew? In which areas lie the main differences? Can any Jew or Israeli today understand what is written in the Hebrew Bible freely or he needs a special training for that? Can anyone, please, provide here an overview?

Comment: A distinction needs to be made between Israelis (who speak Modern Hebrew) and Jews (only about half of whom speak Modern Hebrew).

Comment: Migrate: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/q/4076/47895

Comment: @Tzvi - Thanks for this specification. Would you please tell me why Jews don't speak Modern Hebrew? My knowledge in this area is almost zero.

Comment: @DoubleAA, we can't migrate to a site that doesn't exist. Is the question on-topic here or not?

Comment: brilliant, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I know. I do think it is off topic per the [FAQ](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq) which explicitly excludes general questions about Hebrew language.

Comment: The scope question is continued to http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/948, q.v.

Comment: I hereby nominate this question for reopening. If our site is not for questions like this, what is it for?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/51421/472

Comment: @SAH It is for questions about Judaism as outlined in the [faq] and [help].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Classical Hebrew is more *compact* than modern Hebrew. The are no redundant words in Torah, hence you can see usage of "ובלכתך" instead of "כאשר אתה תלך" and alike.

A Jew (even not a religious one) can understand most parts of the Torah without special training. More problematic parts are description of offerings with much details of how and where each type of offering should be done.

Also poetic parts like [Song of Sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_of_the_sea) and [Haazinu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haazinu) are relatively hard to understand.

Source: personal impression.

Comment: there are also some different uses of past and future tense.  i.e. a past tense command with the letter vav in front of it becomes future tense, and vice versa.  Thus, ידבר in modern Hebrew means "he will speak", but "וידבר" in biblical Hebrew means "and he spoke".  This, and a few other linguistic mechanics, might prevent a secular, modern Hebrew speaker from completely understanding the text without additional training.

Comment: @Will That's only if the vav is punctuated in a certain way.

Comment: @Will Usually, out of the context you understand that the text describes something that occurred in past. So, I think this is not a problem for a common Hebrew-speaker

Comment: What do you make of כי אני הכבדתי את לבו. Is the אני really necessary or more compact?

Comment: @DoubleAA I haven't presented a rule that is always 100% correct in all cases. Just common impression about the differences between Torah Hebrew and modern Hebrew. Anyway,

Comment: @jutky "The are no redundant words in Torah."

Comment: @DoubleAA, That is a statement that is taken as an axiom for many a Bible commentator. The consequence is that things are contracted as in the example jutky gives for the most part, and when they are not, they must be explained away as being required for emphasis specific to that case.

Comment: @jake I know what he meant. I just think rules of parshanut are irrelevant to a discussion of the language. The question asked about the languages, and on the super-simplest pshat level, that word אני is extra because languages do that. From a language perspective all he can say is that combined structures are more common/customary, not that they are exclusive.

Comment: @DoubleAA I've said "The Classical Hebrew is *more* compact", not that is *the most compact* way to describe something. The cause is: *no-redundant-words* constraint, which is surely affects the way things are described. Once again, parshanut is not the main issue of an answer, just a reason for more common use of compact language forms. Doesn't that clear from the answer?

Comment: Sure, the first sentence of your answer is fine! But the second one is not. It should say: "Therefore, there are fewer redundant words in Torah." If you are making a language claim, then sentence 2 follows from sentence 1. If you are making a parshanut claim, then 1 follows from 2. In your most recent comment you indicate the latter. Therein lies my problem.

Comment: @DoubleAA both sentences looks fine to me. If you feel it is problematic, you are welcomed to edit.

Comment: I'm not going to edit as I think this question is off topic anyway. The answers can be as bad as they want as far as I'm concerned. But I'm amazed that you really think "There are no redundant words in Torah" is a claim about the language, not parshanut?? What about some other text written in biblical hebrew? The question asked about the classical hebrew **language**, not about how we interpret the Torah.

Comment: @jutky, there are redundant words, as has been pointed out. I hear what you are saying, but the language is confusing. There are, in fact, redundant words, which sparks questions by some, even many commentators, but there are, in fact, redundant words. I'd suggest more that the _style_ of Biblical Hebrew is to write in a more compact and elegant way, but that is not necessarily a difference in the language.

Comment: @SethJ if we or even commentators do not know what we learn from a specific word in Torah, it still does not means that the word is "in fact" redundant.

Comment: @jutky, I think you're using the word redundant to mean superfluous, when linguistically it doesn't mean that. That's my only point about "redundancy". The Torah could have been written even more concisely than it was, yet that doesn't mean that shorter language is the defining characteristic of the _language_ itself. It's a characteristic of the _style_ in which it was written.

Comment: @SethJ A couple of years later I'm a bit more experienced in English, and I admit that your comment about redundant vs superfluous is totally correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Another difference is that classical Hebrew generally uses a VSO word order (verb, subject, object), while modern Hebrew is generally SVO. As an example, the common phrase in the Torah, וידבר ה' אל משה, would literally translate as "and He spoke, G-d, to Moses"; a modern Hebrew speaker would probably say something like ה' דיבר אל משה.

Answer (score 6):

for a proper overview I would probably send you to Hebrew wikipedia, but I'm guessing you (and most readers) are English speakers, so instead read: [Revival Of the Hebrew Language on wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revival_of_the_Hebrew_language)

As a side note I'll add, as a native (Israeli) Hebrew speaker that an incredibly great majority of the Hebrew Bible is readily understandable with no further sources. As other answers point out several parts are harder to understand with particular examples which pop to mind:

- Leviticus - full of "gory" details of sacrifice and sacrificial procedures
- Several scriptures which are mainly not in Hebrew or incorporate subjects which are non-Hebrew: Esther, Daniel (mostly Aramaic IIRC)

Hope that helps

Comment: Maybe you mean Ezra? Esther is almost entirely in Hebrew.

Comment: I don't know about Leviticus being particularly difficult, really. True that there are some technical and anatomical terms that aren't in common use (מלק, פדר, עצה), but most of the terminology is readily understandable - and indeed has served as a source for modern Hebrew with at most slight variations, such as נתח ("dissect") having become the term for "surgery."

Comment: @Alex I tend to agree with you, but let's not forget the sections about tzaraat.

Comment: @DoubleAA I meant Esther as it contains Persian terms and names which are never used in Hebrew (e.g. האחשדרפנים ), but it isn't unique by any means with "foreign" words in it

Comment: @Yoni Your talking about 20 words or so in the whole book where it is usually clear that it is referring to some sort of ruler (HaPartemim) or messenger (HaAchasteranim). Seems relatively minor, especially compared to Daniel.